# Node js Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately

Tags: node.js

I have just upgraded to Express version 3 and I am seeing an error in my middleware. Specifically:

`Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.`

The stack trace is:

```
at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/phpsaravana/nodeshop/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
at module.exports (/home/phpsaravana/nodeshop/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:30:39)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/phpsaravana/nodeshop/admin.js:6:42)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you have to import express-session

Answer (score 33):

In newer versions of express, middle-wares like session are not bundled with express. Furthermore, if you want to use them, then you have to install them separately. like :

```
 npm install express-session
```

and then require it :

```
var session = require('express-session');
```

and then use this:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

Comment: Sure.Thanks for respond my question. still i had same problem

Comment: are you adding this to your app :

`app.use(session({secret:'secretKey'}));` ?

Comment: Nope. 

app.use(express.session({
        // Set up MongoDB session storage
        store: new mongoStore({url:config.connection}),
        // Set session to expire after 21 days
        cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 181440000)},
        // Get session secret from config file
        secret: config.cookie_secret
        }));

Comment: most likely you are still writing `app.use(express.session())`. Session is no longer owned by Express.

Comment: where do you require it?  Tryng to get an older angular app off the ground

Answer (score 12):

I think your problem is about upgrading from express 2 to 3. In Express 3, most of the package previously bundled with them, are now single package that you need to require, in your app.

Of course you need to include it in your package.json and do the npm install as usual.

```
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')

var app = express()

app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat'}))
```

See: [ExpressJS / Session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)