# Node js ignoring unbundled middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have some issue with middleware that is no longer budnled with NODE.js
I made just like here:

[Node js Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016981/node-js-error-most-middleware-like-session-is-no-longer-bundled-with-express)

But i still got the same error: "Most middleware bla bla bla..."

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('config');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
var IS_DEV = (app.get('env') === 'development');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);

app.use(session({
  secret: config.get('session:secret'),
  key: config.get('session:key'),
  cookie: config.get('session:cookie'),
  store: new MongoStore({mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection})
}));
```

Package installed and i see it in `node_modules` folder. And i don't see any errors like: `session is undefined` What i did wrong?

*Btw same going on with `express-error-handler` package*

- windows 8.1
- node 4.4.0
- mongodb 3.2.4
- npm 2.14.20
- express 4.13.4

Responce:

```
Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
[1]     at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (C:\Work\todoapp\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:99:13)
[1]     at connectMongo (C:\Work\todoapp\node_modules\connect-    mongo\src\index.js:48:43)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\todoapp\app.js:10:42)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[1]     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
[1]     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\todoapp\bin\www:7:11)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[1]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
[1]     at startup (node.js:139:18)
[1]     at node.js:968:3
[1] Program node --debug ./bin/www exited with code 1
[1]
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error that you're getting? It will tell you which middleware that you're using has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Express 4, the setup for `connect-mongo` is incorrect.

It should be:

```
var session = require('express-session');
...
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
                                          ^^^^^^^ not `express`
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#express-or-connect-integration).

Comment: Thanks it fixed this issue but i got another
`Error: Connection strategy not found at MongoStore (C:\Work\todoapp\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:104:23`

Comment: @Strangerliquid you probably need to call `mongoose.connect()` before you call `new MongoStore()` ([doc](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#re-use-a-mongoose-connection))

Comment: C:\Work\todoapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:242

process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:28018

at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)

at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)

at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)

Program node --debug ./bin/www exited with code 1

I guess this is because mongoose is connected already there - it uses same port value cause i copied settings here:
store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})

Comment: The regular port for MongoDB is 27017, not 28018.