# Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately

Tags: node.js, session, express, npm

I'm trying to execute `npm run dev` whenever I execute this, I get this error

```
Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
```

I was searching for similar question and found this post.
[Node js Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016981/node-js-error-most-middleware-like-session-is-no-longer-bundled-with-express)

I did `npm install connect` and `npm install express-session`, but still I keep getting the same error.

Node Version: v6.10.3 
NPM Version: v5.4.0

Comment: which version of express do you use? If 2 or 3 update it to 4. And show me your express code.

Comment: `"express": "^4.15.3",`, this is the express version

Comment: You have to show me your express code so that I can find whether you are using wrong middleware